# PHP mariaDB updating token in database

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb

i have some trouble to find the correct syntax to update a token in a database.

I'm having some trouble trying to fine the correct syntax in order to write a query that updates a token in the database.

This is what my current attempt looks like:

```php
$sql = "UPDATE ComptePro 
    SET `Token` = :Token, 
    WHERE `Index` = :Index";

echo $Indexuser;
echo " ";
echo $token;
$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$req->bindParam(':Token', $token, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->bindParam(':Index', $Indexuser, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$req->execute();
```

Though this is the error I am getting:

[image: img]

Comment: Remove the comma after `:Token` in the `$sql` string. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html for the syntax guide

Comment: thx !!! you save me =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "UPDATE ComptePro 
    SET `Token` = :Token, <----problem is here
    WHERE `Index` = :Index";
```

If you remove the comma, that code should run ok